# Generating a routing database for the entire world while keeping the tags

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po

I've been looking into this matter for a few days now, but I haven't come up with a working solution.

Basically, what we are trying to do is create an entire world database, preferably in PostgreSQL, using PostGIS. Our world file is the whole planet data, in a pbf format (~34GB).

So far, I have tried using the osm2pgrouting and osm2po tools to generate this database, but both tools failed for the setup that we are using.

Our machine is a linux x64 ubuntu-server, with 20 GB of RAM plus 20 GB of swap area. We are using an HHD of 2TB for this.

In my last try with osm2po, I tried running it with 18 GB of ram (`-Xmx18432m`), but it failed after some time. I will be trying again with more memory allocated to the java virtual machine and report the results.

But mainly, my main questions here are:

- Is it possible to generate a routing database for the entire world with these tools and our current machine?
- Is RAM allocation the only optimization that I can do to allow osm2po to handle large files?
- Can osm2po save nodes tags in the PostgreSQL database? I know this is possible for the ways table, since it already exists in the database and even has a column called `osm_meta`, and I also know that it is possible to retrieve this info while reading osm data file, but my guess is that this data will only be available to the front-end part of osm2po.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A month ago a friend of mine asked me to convert the topology for all walkable streets of the planet file with osm2po. We finally agreed to exclude motorways but to include everything from trunk to track. It took about 5 hours on (don't ask me for details) a dedicated linux server with 24Gig RAM.
Okay, osm2po does lot's of preprocessing stuff and applies filters in order to reduce data as early as possible. If you really need each piece of information, you've got to fall back to databasing and have to wait for days, not for hours.

You asked *Is RAM allocation the only optimization that I can do to allow osm2po to handle large files?* ...

**No**, there is a tiling-strategy which exactly will be needed here

You asked *Can osm2po save nodes tags* ...

It depends on what you you are going to convert. Simple cases like taking bollards or traffic signals into account are possible and will be written to the SQL respectively.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more about the *tilling-strategy* things that you mentioned? As for the tags that we want to keep, those would be mostly traffic lights, bumpers, stop signs, and whatever can make your car stop or slowdown. I believe most of these are kept in nodes, but I am not very familiar with the OSM data. Also, I've seen a post where someone wrote a plugin for rail roads scheduling, but I failed to reproduce that. I will retry this in the future, though. The traffic lights example tough, does not generate any extra entries in the database, AFAIK.

Comment: Please read **current on-screen help** on the web page and look for **tileSize**. Furthermore look at this interesting discussion: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/dont-route-through-bollards-concrete-blocks-etc-with-osm2po#answer-57245

Answer (score 1):

I was able to import a full planet file in about 5 days using osm2pgsql with almost the same machine specs you have.

You could do that, then use the PGRouting [Calculate Topology](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/topology.html#load-network-data) functions (plus the other info on that page) to build your network.

This has the added advantage of giving you a PostGis database with all the tags as well to use for queries or Map Rendering.

Have a look at [THIS Blog Post](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2011/10/using-pgrouting-on-osm-database.html) but be aware that you need to change the Create Table Statement to the following:

```
create table network(gid bigserial, osm_id bigint, name varchar, the_geom geometry, source bigint, target bigint, length float);
```

Installing PGSql is a breeze on Trusty, with Postgres 9.3 I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting
sudo apt-get update

psql -U username -d dbname
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
/q
```

Then I ran the Sql from the blog post above to split the ways into routeable segments and create a network graph, however I found I had to modify it to not fail on errors and remove the NOTICES, so here is wht I used

```
drop table if exists network;
create table network(gid bigserial, osm_id bigint, name varchar, the_geom geometry, source bigint, target bigint, length float);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compute_network() RETURNS text as $$
DECLARE
streetRecord record;
wayRecord record;
pointCount integer;
pointIndex integer;
geomFragment record;
BEGIN
-- for each street

--FOR streetRecord in select way, osm_id, name from planet_osm_line where highway is not null and st_contains((select way from planet_osm_polygon where boundary = 'administrative' and name like 'Sector 1' limit 1), way) LOOP

    FOR streetRecord in select way, osm_id, name from planet_osm_line where highway is not null LOOP

   -- for each street in the region of interest
   SELECT * from planet_osm_ways where id = streetRecord.osm_id into wayRecord; 

   BEGIN
       FOR pointIndex in array_lower(wayRecord.nodes, 1)..array_upper(wayRecord.nodes,1)-1 LOOP
           -- RAISE NOTICE 'Inserting name % source %, target %', streetRecord.name, wayRecord.nodes[pointIndex], wayRecord.nodes[pointIndex+1];
           select st_makeline(st_pointn(streetRecord.way, pointIndex), st_pointn(streetRecord.way, pointIndex+1)) as way into geomFragment;
           insert into network(osm_id, name, the_geom, source, target, length) values(streetRecord.osm_id, streetRecord.name, geomFragment.way, wayRecord.nodes[pointIndex], wayRecord.nodes[pointIndex+1], st_length(geomFragment.way));
       END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'ERROR: on streetRecord Id - % - Name < % >' ,streetRecord.osm_id,  streetRecord.name;
   END;
END LOOP;

 return 'Done';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select * from compute_network();
```

The blog is also incorrect, it does not use assign_vertex, it should be

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('network', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

I have not actually done any routing yet. Suggest you try it on a small country extract first. We will be doing the whole planet eventually when I am sure I have enough disk space for the network graph

Comment: i recommend to modify  postgresql.conf to have bigger memory limits after installation

Comment: I am doing some tests based on your answer, and I want to point a small observation: `osm2pgsql` imports by default in spherical mercator coordinates. 

To change to geographics coordinates I made the following change: 

`FOR streetRecord in select ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(planet_osm_line.way,900913),4326) as way, osm_id, name, z_order from planet_osm_line where highway is not null LOOP`.

I will keep looking into this answer to confirm that it attends my needs before marking this one as the solution, 'cause I want to try all approaches first.

Also, thanks for taking the time to write it.

Comment: Can't upvote with less than 15 points :/

Comment: A few things that I noticed: Using the osm_id on the `source` and `target` columns are being overridden by the `pgr_createTopology` function. No references to those Ids are being kept in the new tables. It is also not *optimizing* the database for routing since curves (and even straight roads) that contain a lot of nodes are not being merged into a single geometry line. Maybe I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have not got as far as checking the actual geometry. It would be possible to use [st_simplify](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Simplify.html) to reduce the number of nodes on each segment created if you wanted to.

Comment: I left ours in EPSG:900913 as it defaults to meters on tolerances and distances.

Comment: The documentation on [pgr_createTopology](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/create_topology.html#pgr-create-topology) warns that the source and target values will change, but I do not yet understand why!

Comment: My guess is that: [pgr_createTopology](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/create_topology.html#pgr-create-topology) check for intersections between the geometries in the `the_geom` column. When they exist for the current record, they create a new index in the `network_vertices_pgr` table. This is the value being used on those columns.

Comment: [ST_SIMPLIFY](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Simplify.html) will reduce the number of points into a single line, but I don't think this is going to help us here, since all our entries in the `the_geom` column are simple lines `LINESTRING( PointA, PointB )`.

Comment: I searched through the **pgRouting** docs, but I haven't found a function that does this type of optimization. Techcnically, we could write one ourselves. We need to find nodes have a connection in the format A----B----C, and then erase B and link A to C. I am looking at the osm2pgrouting source code to see how they implement this. If I figure something out I will post here.

Comment: It is not pgrouting, it is a PostGis function, that link I provided is to the page describing its use.

Answer (score 0):

So, after following [Carsten](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8766/carsten)'s suggestion from the comments, I could finally generate a routing database for the entire world.

The catch was to use the `tileSize` command line argument from `osm2po`. The actual values that I used were `java -Xmx8192m -jar osm2po-core-4.8.8-signed.jar prefix=world tileSize=10x10,1.0 planet-140430.osm.pbf` in case you are wondering it.

This generated a sql script of 44GB (14GB zipped). `osm2po`also keeps the original OSM nodes id in the columns `osm_source_id` and `osm_target_id`, which gives me the means to query the tags from a `osm2pgsql` generated database.

Unfortunately, I couldn't make a optimized routing database from [Mark C](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/17846/mark-c)'s suggestion, and I don't think there is an easy way to do that by following that path.

Thank you all for the support.

Comment: If you need the road network only (no footways, tracks, etc.) **tileSize=30x30,1.0,c** should do it as well, but a lot faster. Even **45x45,1,c** might work, but drives osm2po's to its limit. And... use **c**