# How to add our own routing data from postgresql into osm2po graph

Tags: postgis, routing, osm2po

Is there any way to convert data from a PostgreSQL noded table into an `osm2po` graph? this library is able to read `pbf` data and generate a graph from osm data but If I want to update roads data it is not possible. I can update a PostgreSQL database which contains osm data but have no idea if it is possible to deploy them into an `osm2po` graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry it's not. osm2po is a chain of many conversion steps. The generated postgres table is only one of many.
However, technically osm2po is prepared for custom sources. But this has to be implemented per use case and input format individually.

Comment: thanks very much. so it is possible to write some kind of input plugins for osm2po?is there any examples how to write them?I think it would be possible to write readers for postgresql tables

Comment: yes. new input formats (if custom or not) are welcome.
The crucial interface is `OsmParser`. Once there is an implementation you can declare it in the config (one line), so it will be used instead of the default..

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll look at it and check it I can implement a new input format. thanks